# Issues setting up FluentValidation with Castle.Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, fluentvalidation

I have an asp.net MVC 4.5 application with Castle.Windsor 3.2.2 as DI and I'm trying to add FluentValidation version 5.0.0.1 for the first time.

I created the factory inheriting from ValidatorFactoryBase

```
public class WindsorFluentValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorFluentValidatorFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        return _kernel.HasComponent(validatorType)
                     ? _kernel.Resolve<IValidator>(validatorType)
                     : null;
    }
}
```

Also created the installer for Castle:

```
public class FluentValidatorsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Classes
                .FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(IValidator<>))
                .WithService
                .Base());
    }
}
```

Now, in the Global.asax, I tried (following documentation on web) to hook things like this:

```
var fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider = new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(new WindsorFluentValidatorFactory(container.Kernel));
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider);
```

However, the second line gives the following error:

> "The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection.Add(System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidatorProvider)'
>   has some invalid arguments Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'FluentValidation.Mvc.WebApi.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider'
>   to 'System.Web.Mvc.ModelValidatorProvider'"

So, it seems that this way of doing it is not working on the versions I use.

I also tried to hook this using the Configure method doing this:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = new WindsorFluentValidatorFactory(container.Kernel));
```

However, it's not working. Debugging I checked at ModelValidatorProviders.Providers and there is no new provider being add with the Configure method.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks,

Andres

---

Solved
I got a solution in another forum but I'll post the answer it's useful for someone else.
I was using the wrong Provider
There are two providers - one for MVC and one for WebApi. It seems that I was using the WebAPI one.

Changed it to FluentValidation.Mvc.FluentValidationModelValidatorProvide  and the problem was solved

Comment: Post your solution as an answer please, it solved my problem too